# Azure Devops - Restrict write permissions for specific WIT type

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

I want to restrict write permissions for user stories, so that only the PO and the SM will be able to edit user stories in the backlog.

How can I set this?

Answer (score 0):

The permission granularity for workitem is not such meticulous, at most you can set the permission of modify work items under an area path.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#set-permissions-area-path

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible to grant permissions for area paths, but it does not help me... and I think that my use case is quite reasonable, so I wonder why there is no simple way to achieve this.

Comment: @user2717436 I think you may need to request the feature here - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21&preview2=true